# I am integrating SAML with django using djangosaml2 and idp as okta, configured my setting.py file with SAML_CONFIG,

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, saml-2.0

**My settings.py is like**

```
import os
BASEDIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

SAML_CONFIG = {
    "strict": True,
    "debug": True   ,
    "service" :{
    "sp": {

    'name': 'XXX',
     'allow_unsolicited': True,
     'want_assertions_signed': True,  # assertion signing (default=True)
     'want_response_signed': True,
     "want_assertions_or_response_signed": True,  # is response signing required
     'name_id_format': "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:basic",


        "entityId": "https://localhost:8002/metadata/",
        "assertionConsumerService": {
            "url": "https://localhost:8002/?acs",
            "binding": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
        },
        "singleLogoutService": {
            "url": "https://localhost:8002/?sls",
            "binding": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
        },
        "NameIDFormat": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress",
        "x509cert": "",
        "privateKey": ""
    },
    "idp": {
        # "entityId": "https://dev-92033760.okta.com/app/exv13qURtCj35d7/sso/saml/metadata",
        "entityId": "http://www.okta.com/3qURtCj35d7",
        "singleSignOnService": {
            "url": "https://dev-9203760.okta.com/app/dev-92033760_saml4july_1/exRtCj35d7/sso/saml",
            "binding": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
        },
        "singleLogoutService": {
            "url": "https://dev-9233760.okta.com/app/dev-92033760_saml4july_1/exka35d7/sso/saml",
            "binding": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
        },

    },
    },

    'metadata': {
      'local': [os.path.join(BASEDIR, 'remote_metadata.xml')],
      }

}
```

**but getting below after successful redirection from okta**

Authentication Error.
Access Denied.

**and on logs getting**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/zec/label-studio-project/djangosaml2/djangosaml2_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djangosaml2/views.py", line 469, in post
response = client.parse_authn_request_response(
File "/home/zec/label-studio-project/djangosaml2/djangosaml2_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/saml2/client_base.py", line 773, in parse_authn_request_response
raise SAMLError("Missing entity_id specification")
saml2.SAMLError: Missing entity_id specification
Forbidden: /saml2/acs/

Answer (score 0):

Accordin to the [documentation](https://djangosaml2.readthedocs.io/contents/setup.html#custom-and-dynamic-configuration-loading), your entity id, usually your subdomain plus the url to the metadata view .

**try changing :**

```
 "entityId": "https://localhost:8002/metadata/",
```

**to :**

```
 "entityId": "https://localhost:8002/saml2/metadata/",
```